# Find $\lim_{\left\{x,y\right\}\to\left\{1^-,\infty\right\}}x^y$

Tags: limits

As given in the title, the question is to find
$$\lim_{\left\{x,y\right\}\to\left\{1^-,\infty\right\}}x^y$$
When I just input the value of $x$ and $y$, I get $1$, but the answer is $0$, can anyone please help.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of this question?

Comment: @PankajTiwari, yes I do understand the question

Comment: For fixed $0<x<1$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} x^n = 0$
In fact, for the sequence of functions, $f_n(x)=x^n$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ when $0\le x <1$ and $1$ at  $x=1$. Basically the limit function of the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\ge 1}$ is not continuous, so you cannot push the limit inside.

Answer (score 0):

The limit can not be defined.

For example

CASE I. $x_n=e^{-1/n}$ and $y_n=n$, then
$$
x_n^{y_n}=e^{-\frac{1}{n}\cdot n}=e^{-1}
$$
CASE I. $x_n=e^{-1/n}$ and $y_n=n^2$, then
$$
x_n^{y_n}=e^{-\frac{1}{n}\cdot n^2}=e^{-n}\to 0
$$